# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles with multiple filters

Tags: c#, fileinfo, getfiles

I am trying to get a list of FileInfo objects that satisfy multiple filters.

Every suggestion I have seen uses array of file names/paths instead of FileInfo:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sLogPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Where(s => s.StartsWith("abc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || s.StartsWith("def", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sLogPath);
var files = di.GetFiles(<same filter as above>);
```

But it looks like I can only do something like:

```
var files = di.GetFiles("*_" + dateStr + ".log");
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having. `Directory` and `DirectoryInfo` have equivalent `GetFiles` overloads.

Comment: Doesn't Directory,GetFiles return array of strings and DirectoryInfo.GetFiles retrn an array of FileInfo objects?

Comment: I think I see what you want... check out my answer

Comment: Look at modern [File globbing in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing)

Comment: In the first code block, if you append `.Select(f => new FileInfo(f));` you'll get `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`. If you want a list, call also `ToList()`. You can do one-liner query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to me on your question, it looks like you want to filter on file names, but get the `FileInfo`s that correspond to these names.

You can do something like this

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(sLogPath);

var files = di
    .GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("abc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        || x.Name.StartsWith("def", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

We're using the `Name` property in the filter and working with the `FileInfo[]` array returned by [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-7.0#system-io-directoryinfo-getfiles(system-string-system-io-searchoption)).

Comment: thank you. It seems this also returns array of strings. I tried to cast it using                     lsFiles.AddRange((IEnumerable<FileInfo>)files); where lsFiles is list of FileInfo but it throws System.InvalidCastException error.

Comment: @NoBullMan Remove the `.Name` property to select the `x`, the `FileInfo`. Or remove the `.Select` method and use the `Name` property in the `.Where` clause. i.e. `x.Name.StartsWith("abc"....`.

Comment: @NoBullMan Not sure what you're talking about. [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilessystem-io-directoryinfo-getfiles(system-string-system-io-searchoption)) returns `FileInfo[]`.

Comment: Thanks, removing .select and using s.Name instead of s did the job. Marked it as answer.

Comment: @Kit `.Select(x => x.Name)`. You're selecting the `Name` property in your code not the `FileInfo` itself. Thus, the result is `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Ah, I think I didn't exactly register the first sentence of the question! I'll fixup the answer.